# React array dinâmico em imgs

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho a seguinte função criar array dinâmico.

```html
funcListMap(_ref) {  
  let list = [];
  _ref.map((i) => {
   list.push(
     <ListItem key={i.id}>
      <h1>{i.id}</h1>
      <span>{i.descricao}</span>
      <img src={require(`'${i.img}'`)} />
      <span>{i.valor}</span>
      </ListItem>
   )
  })
  return (list);
 }
```

1. Só que está dando erro na hora de carregar a imagem

   ```
   <Img src={require(`'${i.img}'`)} />
   // Ou se tentar assim
   <Img src={require(i.imagens)}/>
   ```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Más se eu colocar um o caminho de forma manualmente funciona, ou seja carrega a mesma imagem para todos.

   ```
   <Img src={require('../statics/imagens/sanduiches/sanduiche-01.png')} />
   ```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver a questão desta código

```
<Img src={require(`'${i.img}'`)} /> ou <Img src={require(i.imagens)}/>
```

Comment: Não precisa do `require`, é só fazer `<img src={i.img}/>`

Comment: E por que em um teste você usa i.img e no outro usa i.imagens? Qual é o nome correto?

Comment: é porque eu estava testando com outros nomes, mas estou usando apenas i.img, mesmo, de qualquer forma , quando vou puxar uma imagem local não funciona. Desta forma <img src={i.img} />  pegando uma da web como http://sitequalquer/imagem.png, funcinona, mas, seu informar  http://localhost/diretorio/imagem.png, não funciona! nao carrega imagem local.

Answer (score 2):

Não há necessidade de utilizar `require` veja esse simples exemplo:

```js
let Carros = [
  {
    id: 1,
    descricao: 'Fiat Toro',
    img: 'http://www.fiat.com.br/content/dam/fiat-brasil/desktop/produtos/modelos/226/versoes/22611X0/176.png'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    descricao: 'Fiat Argo',
    img: 'http://argo.fiat.com.br/modules/home/data/tablet/background.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    descricao: 'Golf 2017',
    img: 'https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-bnzlXa1mIe0/WCXcyVh9aNI/AAAAAAAA1_g/xbgbYXeSCLQc7y5gXagH2SZhZW_SAtdzwCLcB/s1600/Novo-Golf-2017%2B%252815%2529.jpg'
  }
];
var Images = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>  {Carros.map(function(i){
              return (
              <div key={i.id}>
                <h1>{i.id}</h1>
                <span>{i.descricao}</span>
                <img src={i.img} width='120' />
                <span>{i.valor}</span>
              </div>
              );
      })}
  </div>
  )
}
                               });
ReactDOM.render(<Images />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: vou tentar este exemplo, para ver se funciona, a questão é que imagem com o endereço da web funciona, normalmente. mas quando o endereço é localhost, http://localhost:3000/dir/img.png (não carrega)

Comment: Se estiver usando distribuições *Linux* tem que verificar as permissões de acesso, veja qual é o Erro que está retornando no `Console`